# SSH Key Authentication on Synology NAS

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, synology

On my Synology NAS, I can't get SSH key authentication working. I have tried all the usual things (added to authorized_keys, edited sshd config, ...), and still haven't been able to get it working.

I'd really like to be able to run interaction-free transfers to my NAS with SCP.

Additionally, another IT friend I spoke to said he got it working a while back, but it was a big pain and doesn't remember how.

Has anyone gotten this working?

Comment: We are certainly glad you found a solution, but please don't put "Solved" in the title of your question. Within our community, the fact that you designated an answer as the official solution already shows us that the problem has been solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the tip Run5k. I'm relatively new, and still learning the unwritten rules.

Comment: Always glad to help.  Thank *you* for the follow-up and the accepted answer!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Although none of the other answers directly fixed it, I took some of their methods and combined them.

This is what worked for me on my Synology DS414slim, running DSM 6.1.

I logged in as `admin` and executed the following command (no need to fill in your username, it will work as-is):

This will set your home directory to `700` permission, owned by `[you]:users`.

```
homedir=$(eval echo ~$USER); 
sudo chown $USER:users $homedir -R;
chmod 700 $homedir; 
chmod 700 $homedir/.ssh/;
chmod 600 $homedir/.ssh/authorized_keys;
```

Comment: this method worked for me on my Synology DS216j running DSM 6.2.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I got it working by following tips in the comments here: https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=90208

Short version, run `chmod -R 755 ~`. Dir perms were too permissive (?!) for ssh to use public key authentication. No idea if this causes other conflicts, but it works.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: I agree with Donald Duck. If you edit, Nobody, I'll set this as accepted answer.

Comment: And else you just add the answer yourself and mark it as community wiki. :)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me so it couldn't have been *that* hard to set up. I'm using a DS1812+ with DSM 6.0.2-8451 Update 5

Try creating a new user with read/write permissions on "homes"

Verify that you can ssh into the account with a password.

Either

- add your id_rsa.pub to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
- or `ssh-copy-id new_user@synology_box`

If it doesn't work, try using verbose mode: `ssh -vvv new_user@synology_box`. There might be something obvious there.

Answer (score 0):

DSM 6

1. chmod not only .ssh but also your home dir to 700
2. chown not only .ssh but also your home dir to root:root

ex:

```
 sudo -i
 chown root:root /var/service/home/username
 chmod 700 /var/service/home/username
```

Comment: Um, that means I can't access my home directory if I set it owned by someone else, and give myself 0 permission.

Answer (score 0):

I only had to do the following to get it working:

1. Enable use of home directory using the web interface (Advanced settings)
2. Change directory permissions for the home directory (NAS)

   sudo -i

   chmod -R 755 ~
3. Then it was possible to generate keys and copy to the .ssh directory of that account (Client)

   ssh-keygen -t rsa

   ssh-copy-id account@synology_server

Answer (score 0):

Synology providing guide, how use ssh keys : 

https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Management/How_to_log_in_to_DSM_with_key_pairs_as_admin_or_root_permission_via_SSH_on_computers#b_8